# how to fix MissingMethodException error, produced by method call from an, in an interface initiated, class

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, interface, missingmethodexception

I'm creating an api and inside a controller I want to call a method, this method belongs to a class, namespaceService. I create a new instance of this class whenever I create a new Instance of the class k8sClient. To use the k8sClient class inside my api I created a interface of this class Ik8sClient.
Whenever I call the method, which is called GetNamespaces, I get a MissingMethodException.

The full exception is as follows: "MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'k8s.Models.V1NamespaceList k8s.KubernetesExtensions.ListNamespace(k8s.IKubernetes, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1<Int32>, System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.Nullable`1, System.String)'."

This is my code:

NamespacesController

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Administration.Libary;
using Administration.Model;
using k8s.Models;


namespace Administration.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NamespacesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IK8sClient _k8sClient;
        public NamespacesController(IK8sClient client)
        {
            _k8sClient = client;
        }

        //GET: api/namespaces   
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<NameSpace>> GetNamespaces()
        {

            var result = await _k8sClient.nsService.GetNamespaces();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

K8sClient.cs

```cs
using k8s;
using System;
namespace Administration.Libary
{
    public class K8sClient : IK8sClient
    {
        private readonly Kubernetes _k8sClient = null;
        public NamespaceService nsService { get;  private set; }

        public Kubernetes Client
        {
            get
            {
                return _k8sClient;
            }
        }

        public K8sClient()
        {
            string kubeConfigFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "kubeconfig");             
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(kubeConfigFile)) throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Kube config file not found");
            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile(kubeConfigFile);
            _k8sClient = new Kubernetes(config);
            InitiateServices(this);
        }


        public void InitiateServices(K8sClient client)
        {
            if (client == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Client was null.");

            nsService = new NamespaceService(client);

        }

        private bool _disposed;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _k8sClient.Dispose();
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    public interface IK8sClient : IDisposable
    {
        Kubernetes Client { get; }
        NamespaceService nsService { get; }
        void InitiateServices(K8sClient client);       
    }
```

NamespaceService.cs

```cs
using Administration.Model;
using k8s;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Administration.Libary
{
    public class NamespaceService
    {
        private IK8sClient _k8sClient;
        private CreateNsService createNsService;

        public NamespaceService(K8sClient client)
        {
            _k8sClient = client;
            createNsService = new CreateNsService(client);
        }

        public NameSpace selectedNamespace;
        private List<string> namespacesToIgnore = new List<string> { "default", "kube-node-lease", "kube-public", "kube-system"};

        public Task<List<NameSpace>> GetNamespaces()
        {
            var namespaceList = new Task<List<NameSpace>>(() => new List<NameSpace>());
            var namespaces = _k8sClient.Client.ListNamespace();
            foreach (var ns in namespaces.Items)
            {
                string nsName = ns.Metadata.Name;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nsName))
                    throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve namespace ID.");

                if (!namespacesToIgnore.Contains(nsName) && ns.Status.Phase != "Terminating")
                {
                    namespaceList.Result.Add(new NameSpace()
                    {
                        Id = ns.Metadata.Name
                    });
                }
            }

            return namespaceList;
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Administration.Libary;

namespaceAdministration.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddScoped<IK8sClient, K8sClient>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

    }

}
```

The line which should throw the error is: "var namespaces = _k8sClient.Client.ListNamespace();" in the NamespaceService class. It's also notable that I can't enter my NamespaceService class while debugging, when I set a breakpoint in the class it never stops there, even tho it appears that my program enters the class.

Comment: Yeah so there's an old `k8s.dll` floating around somewhere, wherein the `Kubernetes` class doesn't have the method `ListNamespace()`.  Have you tried reading [ask] and researching this error? See for example [Diagnosing MissingMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163888/diagnosing-missingmethodexception).

Comment: I have yes, but I did not find that, so thanks

Comment: So it turns out it was caused by a version mismatch in the k8sClient dependencies of my projects.