# Assembly/DLL loading

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, .net-assembly

I am using a shared DLL. In my Main() I add a handler to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve which loads the DLL. This works for some of my programs, others crash before even getting into Main() with a System.IO.FileNotFoundException (it could not locate the DLL file).

Does anybody know why some of my programs try to load the DLL before getting into Main() and others do not? What must I change to prevent the loading of the DLL before reaching Main()?

Comment: Show your code. If you hook into the AssemblyResolve event, it gets fired for _every_ assembly that the runtime looks for. So if you use a type in your Main() that's from another assembly, your event handler will be called.

Comment: using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AddAssemblyResolver();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FormMain());
        }
    }
}

Comment: No show your code in the event handler. [edit] all code into the question

Comment: I add the AssemblyResolve handler in Main(), but it will of course not be called when the program crashes before reaching Main()... @CodeCaster

Comment: The event handler is never called @Charlieface. The program crashes before reaching Main() where I attach the handler!

Comment: If it tries to JIT compile `Main` itself and that is where the call to this assembly is, then you can't catch that. You need to put any code which use those assemblies into another function

Comment: Only subscribe the event in Main(), the rest of the code needs to be moved into another method.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16166432/17034).

Comment: @Charlieface I don't understand "You need to put any code which use those assemblies into another function". What kind of function? I think you are right about the JIT. The question is why is does it in some program, and not others. They use the DLL in the same manner

Comment: If there is code directly in `Main` that refers to this DLL then `Main` cannot even be compiled. Sometimes things will also be inlined so it may be code that `Main` calls also. Perhaps put `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` attribute on `Main`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the suggestion but it did not help. I am not referring to the DLL in Main(). Main only has 4 lines. The first sets up the event handler for AssemblyResolve and the next 3 are the ones that Visual Studio make for you when you create the project. And it's the same 4 lines in all my programs. That's why it's such a puzzle for me. In the programs that work the Main() is reached and when the last line creates the main form the event handler gets called and loads the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a repro. As stressed, it is important that you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

It involves a public enum property (`Address.All` in your case). When I deploy this program and remove the shared DLL, this throws without invoking my event handler:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolveHandler;

        Console.WriteLine("In Main()");

        _ = new Foo();
    }

    private static Assembly AssemblyResolveHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("I'm afraid I can't do that, Dave.");
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Foo constructor");
    }

    public SharedClassLibrary.SharedEnum Unused { get; set; }
}
```

The shared class library consists of just this:

```
namespace SharedClassLibrary
{
    public enum SharedEnum
    {
        Zero = 0,
        One = 1
    }
}
```

Running this program without the shared DLL present throws a `FileNotFoundException` complaining about a missing DLL even before entering the Main() method.

So the solution is to have the assembly next to your executable, I don't know why you want to involve your own assembly loading code.

The cause is the JIT, wanting to know everything about the types used within the `Main()` method. This type `Foo` is used, and in order to instantiate it, the runtime has to know everything about `Foo`, among others to be able to allocate memory for the instance.

Part of `Foo` is an enum, and since enums can inherit from various numeric types with varying sizes (one byte or more), the runtime wants to look up the enum's definition, hence has to load the assembly.

The workaround is to instantiate your form in a new method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolveHandler;

    Console.WriteLine("In Main()");

    RunApplication();
}

private static void RunApplication()
{
    _ = new Foo();
    // or in your case, Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

This shows that my custom assembly resolver is hit:

> In Main()
>
> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'SharedClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Not implemented (0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))
> File name: 'SharedClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>
> ---> System.NotImplementedException: I'm afraid I can't do that, Dave.

Comment: Yes, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AddAssemblyResolver is an extension, but no, not used in my shared DLL - its used in the programs that uses the DLL. I do not want to deploy the DLL alongside with my executable, I want to be able to update the DLL and all my programs then get whatever corrections I made in the DLL

Comment: You call the extension method in Main(), therefore the DLL needs to be loaded before your Main() gets executed. If the DLL isn't there, it'll throw. Not sure what more I can tell you.

Comment: As for your deployment strategy, that sounds like an accident waiting to happen. Executables should just reference their dependencies through a package manager like NuGet, you shouldn't manually drop DLLs next to deployed exes.

Comment: But the extension is NOT in the DLL !  I am not installing/dropping my DLL next to my exe. I just refer to in under References

Comment: Then where is it? And what other types do you use in your main method? What does a working Main() look like, and a non-working one? What is the stack trace for the exception you show? Where is the DLL in those cases? Create a [mre].

Comment: Some of my program reach Main() where the extension will add the handler. When Application.Run(new FormMain()); is called the event handler is called and I load the DLL - everything is fint. But for some reason some of my programs never reach Main() because the programs (the JIT !?) tries to load the DLL first. And I dont understand why. The usage of the DLL is the same for all my programs

Comment: Perhaps the non-working programs have static members on their `FormMain` that refer to the shared DLL? Again, we can guess, or you can show relevant code. Again, before your Main() method can run, all types used within it will have to be kind of loaded entirely.

Comment: The Main() is exactly the same in all of my programs (posted earlier).

Comment: Do you want this problem solved or not? I'm not talking about showing your Main() method. You can tell a hundred stories about what your code looks like, or you can provide a [mre] and get some actual help.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to make a reproducible example because I don't know what causes the loading of the DLL happening before Main(). But I can tell you how I managed to get one program working. I had a property defined as Address {get; set;} = Address.All; Address being a enum in the DLL's namespace. And I know it seems insane, but I changed it to: int DoTalkTo;
        Address TalkTo
        {
            get { return (Address)DoTalkTo; }
            set { DoTalkTo = (int)value; }
        }

Comment: That's exactly what I've been telling you.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. Telling me what? :-/

Comment: Try reading my entire answer again.

Comment: I still don't get it. All my programs refer the the DLL in the main form. And why does changing the property Address {get; set;} = Address.All;  to this helps (I am still reffering to the DLL) : int DoTalkTo; Address TalkTo { get { return (Address)DoTalkTo; } set { DoTalkTo = (int)value; } }

Comment: What part don't you get? If the runtime wants to use a type, it has to load that type. You don't access the TalkTo property in your constructor, so it doesn't need to load it yet. It does when you actually use the type in your constructor.

Comment: But the JIT does "lazy loading", right? And I do not use anything from the DLL before my main form is created in Program.cs. So what I don't understand is why handling of a property in my main form change the loading of the DLL? The JIT does not need to know about the DLL before it reaches the 4th code line in Program.cs.  What I really REALLY don't understand is why this single line: "Address TalkTo;" makes the JIT load the DLL, but changing it into this will not:  "int DoTalkTo;  Address TalkTo { get { return (Address)DoTalkTo;} set { DoTalkTo = (int)value; } }"

Comment: It works! And I understand your arguments, but I still don't understand why tampering with the property changes things. But never mind :-) Just to explain why I don't want to have my DLL next to my exe: It contains things like IDs+error codes. 10+ programs use it. When e.g. a new ID is added I could update the programs and installers (even though the programs don't change). Instead I update the DLL and it's installer. This way users can run the DLL-update-installer and all 10+ programs now know the new ID. I guess that placing my DLL in the GAC would also have solved my problem!?

Comment: Doing the following is also a workaround (which I don't understand). Change this single line: public SharedClassLibrary.SharedEnum Unused { get; set; }  To: int ToDo;
        public SharedClassLibrary.SharedEnum Unused 
        { 
            get { return (SharedClassLibrary.SharedEnum)ToDo; } 
            set { ToDo = (int)value; } 
        }

Comment: I can't confirm that right now. As for the GAC, yes, that's a solution for your problem, but that is being phased out. You now have a separate "shared assembly installer" which has to figure out which of your applications are installed, and where they are... I'd rather have all my applications be standalone and self-updating, including their dependencies. But if it works for you, it works. :)

Comment: My shared assembly installer does not have to figure out what programs are installed. It saves (overwrites)  the DLL in Environment.SystemDirectory and all my programs AssemblyResolve load the DLL from that path. :-)

Comment: So you invented your own GAC, got it :D Again, if it works good enough, it's ok.